# Are jobs the only way out for data scientists?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, apache-hadoop

I have reached this point in my data sceince journey that I am left wondering if jobs are the only way out for me...

I am highly skilled in Hadoop, Machine Learning and now getting into Deep Learning algorithms...

I am bored with having to be employed, I want a way out...any ideas? I would still like to use my skills in my life but what other options exist out here...

I am open to ideas and collaborations....

Comment: Are you thinking of becoming self-employed or creating a start-up? Both of these would normally be considered "jobs" in normal use of the English word - however, they do mean that you do do not work _directly_ for an employer. If you can focus your question on to one specific goal that you see as the "way out", and write a question that assumes that is what you want to do (plus phrase it to be about something objective - such as how to best search for start-ups looking for data scientists). You can ask more than one question, in order to keep each focused.

Comment: Another aside: Is an academic career an option for you?

Comment: You could strike gold in quantitive finance and retire ... with low probability.